# Sonar Analysis using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have updated my sonarcube to latest version 5.0 and jenkins to latest version 1.598.
Now when I am trying to build the project and analysis it using sonar, I am facing the below error.
I have checked in jenkins and sonar. Both are having latest version of svn.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project ScrapperDBBatchService: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w --username ******** --password ******** src/main/java/com/chw/hma/service/batch/dao/IBatchMasterDao.java] failed: svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
[ERROR] svn: E155036: The working copy at 'C:\.jenkins\jobs\ScrapperDBService\workspace'
[ERROR] is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.8.5 (r1542147)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

Comment: Configure Jenkins to use most up-to-date svn checkout format. I assume you are using SVN 1.8.X whereas in Jenkins only 1.7 support exist..which I'm not 100%sure.

Answer (score 0):

Update the SonarQube svn plugin

To do that, go to 
http:///updatecenter/updates

I was having a similar issue and updated to 1.1 and that fixed my issue